Jarred grapes in fridge for over a month or so?
Is there anything I can do with grapes left in a sealed jar in the fridge that now taste tingly?  Or throw away? Hate to throw away if I can use them another way?

Sounds like they are fermenting.

You've made sparkling (carbonated) fruit, apparently.
